# SwiftUI: View does not update when state variable changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there anything wrong with this sample code? The `Text` view updates with a one character delay. For example, if I type "123" in the textfield, the `Text` view displays "12".

If I replace `contacts` with a simple structure and change its `givenName` property, then the view updates correctly.

Note that the `print` statement does print correctly (ie, if you type "123" it prints "1" then "12" then "123". So the `contacts.givenName` does get update as it should.

I have see other questions with a similar title, but this code does not seem to have the problems described in any of the questions that I have seen.

```
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var contact = CNMutableContact()


    var body: some View {
         TextField("name", text: $name)
                .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                    contact.givenName = newValue
                    print("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
                }
         Text("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I added an `id` to the Text view and increment it when I update the `contact` state variable. It's not pretty but it works. Other solutions seem to be too involved fro something that shouldn't be this complicated.

```
   struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var contact = CNMutableContact()
    @State var viewID = 0   // change this to foce the view to update
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $name)
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                contact.givenName = newValue
                print("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
                viewID += 1 // force the Text view to update
            }
        Text("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)").id(viewID)
       }
    }
```

Comment: A State propert should be a struct but CNMutableContact is a class. When you change a struct you get a new value which SwiftUI reacts on but for a class the current instance is updated instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The reason your `Text()` shows one character less than the original `name`**:

When inside `onChange { }` closure you update `contact.givenName` it does not refresh/reload your whole view. Because you are not actually updating the whole `contact` @State variable rather you are updating just a property `givenName` of the `contact` @State variable.

By the rules of `@State` variable, when you update the whole `@State` variable only then the view reloads.

Based on this I will share 2 simpler solutions:

**Solution 1: Update the @State variable `contact` object completely**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var contact = CNMutableContact()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $name)
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: name) { oldValue, newValue in
                contact = .init() // Updating the @State variable contact completely
                contact.givenName = newValue
                print("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
            }
        Text("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
    }
}
```

It works fine. But I personally don't like this solution because it creates new `contact` reference each time. **So it is not efficient** in my opinion.

**Solution 2: User another @State var `contactName` to track contact name**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var contactName: String = ""
    
    var contact = CNMutableContact() // We don't need @State for this
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $name)
            .padding()
            .onChange(of: name) { oldValue, newValue in
                contact.givenName = newValue
                contactName = newValue
                print("contact.givenName = \(contact.givenName)")
            }
        Text("contact.givenName = \(contactName)")
    }
}
```

Don't worry, your `contact.givenName` will update accordingly.

Comment: This will create a new `CNMutableContact` every single time the `View` is reevaluated.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I said I recommend the 2nd solution i shared. I already mentioned the problem you mentioned.

Comment: The 2nd solution is the one I was referring to.

Comment: In my 2nd solution `CNMutableContact` will be created only once, when you create the view. Other time during view reevaluation i.e when any @State property changes then, only the `var body` will be recalculated. Which doesn’t create new instance of the `contact`. Only the `contact.givenName` can be updated during view reevaluation.

Comment: No, it will be created every time the view is re-evaluated. In SwiftUI, there is no guarantee that a view will be "created" once. It may be re-evaluated at any time (including when `@State` variables change, if the orientation changes, etc). You can use the debugger and see this happen in your example.

Comment: When @State variable changes only the ‘body’ is recalculated.

Comment: Yes, in the case that it's a `ContentView` `@State` variable. But, if it's higher up in the tree, the `View` may be re-evaluated (in particular, if ContentView had an input coming from the outside). The point I'm making is that this solution works in a vacuum (which, to be fair, this question is), but with almost any added complexity (again, like `ContentView` having a parameter from the outside that ever changes), it will likely end up creating multiple `CNMutableContact`

Comment: Actually my this answer based on this question specifically. If you talk about injecting external input then that’s about separate design principles. In that case I prefer a `viewModel: ObservedObject` to contain all other external dependencies. And other changing properties should be marked with `@Published`. And the `View` should hold the viewModel instance as @ObservedObject. Anyway, that’s a separate scenario.

Answer (score 15):

The cause of this is using `@State` for your `CNMutableContact`.

`@State` works best with value types -- whenever a new value is assigned to the property, it tells the `View` to re-render. In your case, though, `CNMutableContact` is a *reference type*. So, you're not setting a truly new value, you're modifying an already existing value. In this case, the `View` only updates when `name` changes, which then triggers your `onChange`, so there's no update after the `contact` changes and you're always left one step behind.

But, you *need* something like `@State` because otherwise you can't mutate the contact.

There are a couple of solutions to this. I think the simplest one is to wrap your `CNMutableContact` in an `ObservableObject` and call `objectWillChange.send()` explicitly when you change a property on it. That way, the `View` will be re-rendered (even though there aren't any `@Published` properties on it).

```
class ContactViewModel : ObservableObject {
    var contact = CNMutableContact()
    
    func changeGivenName(_ newValue : String) {
        contact.givenName = newValue
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var name: String = ""
    @StateObject private var contactVM = ContactViewModel()

    var body: some View {
         TextField("name", text: $name)
                .onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                    contactVM.changeGivenName(newValue)
                    print("contact.givenName = \(contactVM.contact.givenName)")
                }
        Text("contact.givenName = \(contactVM.contact.givenName)")
    }
}
```

Another option is moving `name` to the view model and using Combine to observe the changes. This works without `objectWillChange` because the `sink` updates `contact` on the same run loop as `name` gets changed, so the `@Published` property wrapper signals the `View` to update after the change to `contact` has been made.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import Contacts

class ContactViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""
    var contact = CNMutableContact()
    
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $name.sink {
            self.contact.givenName = $0
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var contactVM = ContactViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("name", text: $contactVM.name)
        Text("contact.givenName = \(contactVM.contact.givenName)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I updated my question with a workaround that works but it's not pretty. What do you think?

Comment: I would say that although it *works*, the intention is unclear in that case and encourages practices with unintended behavior (like using `@State` for a reference type), whereas both of my solutions have pretty good semantic clarity about  what is actually happening. In terms of your comment that "Other solutions seem to be too involved fro something that shouldn't be this complicated", I'd say my second solution, in particular, is actually less complicated than your original implantation.

Comment: Silly autocorrect -- implantation = implementation